# Convert to a IList type from type specified in dictionary

Tags: c#

I have 4 methods with different return types. I would like to get a count in a generic method, however, the casting I have tried is giving a compiler error

```
enum PayRecType {AA, AB, AC, AD};

private int GetDataPartCount(PayRecType useRecType)
{
    Dictionary<PayRecType, GetValuesStruct> mapAllGet = new Dictionary<PayRecType, GetValuesStruct>()
    {
        { PayRecType.AA, new GetValuesStruct() { RunMethod = GetAARecords, CastAsType = typeof(IList<DDF_AARecord>) } },
        { PayRecType.AB, new GetValuesStruct() { RunMethod = GetABRecords, CastAsType = typeof(IList<DDF_ABRecord>) } },
        { PayRecType.AC, new GetValuesStruct() { RunMethod = GetACRecords, CastAsType = typeof(IList<DDF_ACRecord>) } },
        { PayRecType.AD, new GetValuesStruct() { RunMethod = GetADRecords, CastAsType = typeof(IList<DDF_ADRecord>) } }
    };
    
    //this part works just fine
    var dataList = mapAllGet[useRecType].RunMethod();
    
    if (dataList == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        // this is not working as I need to cast it to get the count - but how?
        return ((mapAllGet[useRecType].CastAsType)dataList).Count;
    }
}

struct GetValuesStruct
{
    public Func<object> RunMethod {get;set;}
    public Type CastAsType {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can use non-generic interfaces for the cast. For example [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-5.0), which exposes [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection.count?view=net-5.0) property:

```cs
return ((ICollection)dataList).Count;
```

If it is not possible in your case, then you will need either to dive into reflection or to consider refactoring your `GetValuesStruct`.

Comment: This unfortunately is not working. Not entirely sure if this is a limitation, but I am stuck using .net 4. Thank you for your input however

Comment: @Arkaine80 _"This unfortunately is not working."_ - can you please be more specific? `ICollection` interface should be available in .NET 4

Comment: ICollection requires a data type - ICollection<?>, and passing in the type from the struct does not work (compiler error). I also tried changing the struct type to DDF_A{0}Record, and tried casting like IList<mapAllGet[useRecType].CastAsType> or ICollection<mapAllGet[useRecType].CastAsType>

Comment: @Arkaine80 as was said in the answer - try using non-generic `ICollection` from  `System.Collections` (add `using System.Collections;` to the top)